# При клике по кнопке присвоить одному блоку display: none, второму: display: inline-block; Как реализовать?

Tags: jquery

Есть две кнопки btn1 и btn2 и есть два блока: block1 (изначально display: block;) и block2 (изначально display: none;), 
хочу связать их в такую комбинацию: 
чтобы при клике по кнопке btn1: первому блоку присваивался display: none; а второму блоку: display: inline-block; 
при клике по btn2: первый блок display:block; второй display: none;
Не силен в jquery, помогите советом или примером. Спасибо.

Comment: Хочешь на js без jquery?

Comment: главное чтобы работало:)

Comment: ответ уже дали, изи)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.btn1').on('click', function(){
     $('.block1').css('display','none');
     $('.block2').css('display','inline-block');
});
$('.btn2').on('click', function(){
     $('.block1').css('display','block');
     $('.block2').css('display','none');
});
```

Comment: Сколько лишних телодвижений, можно одной строкой: `$(".block").toggleClass("hide-box")`

Comment: в вопросе прозвучало не силен в jQuery... а объяснять что такое тугл клас несколько дольше...

Comment: Ну Вы в ответе и так ничего не объясняли) Оставил комментарий, так как может кому-то будет полезно, не более.